# Apache server-status?auto missing Informations

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos

I want to Monitor my Apache Webserver with Cacti and following Plugin

https://github.com/Busindre/Apache-mod_status-Cacti/blob/master/README.md

in the Readme is statet that the Page should look like this:

```
Total Accesses: 824549677
Total kBytes: 39869016655
CPULoad: .25456
Uptime: 7511517
ReqPerSec: 109.771
BytesPerSec: 5435100
BytesPerReq: 49512.9
BusyWorkers: 160
IdleWorkers: 590
ConnsTotal: 4615
ConnsAsyncWriting: 536
ConnsAsyncKeepAlive: 1083
ConnsAsyncClosing: 2776
Scoreboard: LG...
```

But my Status Page is like this

```
Total Accesses: 8325
Total kBytes: 60620
CPULoad: .0371668
Uptime: 223129
ReqPerSec: .0373103
BytesPerSec: 278.202
BytesPerReq: 7456.44
BusyWorkers: 1
IdleWorkers: 9
Scoreboard: _______.W_._....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Im running

httpd.x86_64                          2.4.6-89.el7.centos

VHost conf

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.12:80>
ServerName 192.168.100.12/server-status
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /server-status
RewriteRule ^ - [END]
<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require ip 192.168.100.0/24
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

ExtendStatus is On

Has anyone an idee how i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check which MPM module is being used by httpd daemon right now:

```
httpd -V | grep MPM
```

Probably there is "prefork" or "worker". If so, in terms of "how it works" **there is no such thing** as "async connections" at all. And this situation with "missing" counters is absolutly normal.

Async connections comes to game while MPM "event" module is being used. **Then you will see** these counters.

Each MPM module has its pros and cons, you might want to migrate to "event" module probably but this is a completely different topic.
You can start to going in details reading official Apache [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html).